# cross site authorization doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have one web application hosted on http://localhost:60455 that created with ASP.NET MVC and another web application hosted on http://localhost:52775 that created with ASP.NET Web API + Angular4.

Users login into http://localhost:60455 using WebForm Authentication and cookies, after that user could move to http://localhost:52775 make some actions and return back. At this moment user is not authorized.
Why http://localhost:60455 does not use cookies that were set early?

Answer (score 0):

Locally this *should* work if the 2 sites were running on the same machine but in a production environment it won't work out of the box.

It not allow the token to be passed from system 1 to 2.

The reason is the 2 sites will sign the token with their own MachineKey.

This can be explicitly set in the web.config of each site to allow the tokens to pass between sites but is a little bit of work (I've not personally done it before):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="Decryption key goes here,IsolateApps" 
                validationKey="Validation key goes here,IsolateApps" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, you could opt for a stateless way of authenticating requests from Site A to B. Every request from site A would be signed and the signature authenticated on site B before any action takes place.